# Newbie to React

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a code challenge and am very new to React. I am used to hard coding things, and I need to loop in data from a JS file. I am familiar with HTML and CSS so styling will be no problem, but how I can pull in the data from the menu items without hardcoding. Below are links to what I have in the project files as well as a reference as to what it should look like.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: use the array map function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example

**Interactive sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-lovelace-kr6rr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**Here's the code**:

```
function myComponent() {

    // Here's your data
    // You'll probably want to set this to state after fetching it
    // (It doesn't need to be in a const)
    const myList = [
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtE4X.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/n412K.png", 
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVSl2.png"
        ];

    // map over your data
    // here we are rendering an html img for each item
    // and we give each a key to help react keep a record of what is has rendered
    return (
        <div>
            {myList.map(url => <img src={url} key={url} />)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Jordan ! The data that I need to pass is actually in one of the screenshots. I should have uploaded it there. It is currently in the data.js file and needs to show up in the app.js file. I only had the H1 as the header for combo meals, but name,price,calories, etc lives in data.

Comment: Ah ok @GabeSanchez I misunderstood what you were asking for! I have updated the codepen. The principle is the same - you have to map over each item in the data. Here is the link to the updated code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-lovelace-kr6rr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

On line 19, try

```
let menuItems = this.state.menuItems.map((item) => {
    <MenuItem name={item.name} img={item.imageName} price={item.details.price} />
}
```

Then in your return,

```
<div id="combo-header">
    <h1>Combo Meals</h1>
    {menuItems} 
</div>
```

You can also choose to loop within your render instead of assigning to its own `menuItem` variable.

```
<div id="combo-header">
    <h1>Combo Meals</h1>
    {this.state.menuItems.map((item) => {
        <MenuItem name={item.name} img={item.imageName} price={item.details.price} />
    }}
</div>
```

Note that the second option requires the javascript to be wrapped in {} so that you can write javascript directly in the JSX.

After this, you'd write a MenuItem component that would intake the props above.

You will also have to perform a check that the array is not empty before mapping over it, or there will be errors.